# Parsing an XML Document in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I'm using an xmlreader to parse a valid xml file.  I start reading and have an if statement like so:

```
if (reader.IsStartElement())
{
     // Code needed here
```

How do I grab just the name of that start element?

Comment: Why use `XmlReader`? And I suggest you look at the "Related questions" on the right. And this is not ASP Classic.

Comment: MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaxy929c.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the value of `reader.Name`

```
if (reader.IsStartElement())
{
     if (reader.Name == "settings")
     {
          //do stuff
```

But as the others suggested, you might want to read more documentation about XmlReader, and perhaps even think about simply parsing the full xml document with XDocument etc.

Comment: I think there's typo. reader.Name = "settings" should be changed to ==